# Use variable in quoted part of an @Query

Tags: android, android-room

Trying to write the query using sqlite's date function, but I can't get the variable to be recognized.

I have it written like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE startDate >= :startDate AND startDate < date(:startDate, + ':days day') AND jobId = :jobId")
LiveData<List<Shift>> loadDateRange(LocalDate startDate,@IntRange(from = 1) int days,@IntRange(from = 0) int jobId);
```

I've tried escaping the ' a few different ways, no success.

Building just returns `Unused parameter days`.

Comment: I don't think that is supported.

Comment: @CommonsWare I believe that my answer shows how it can be done (CTE or Subquery as the date function modifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wish to try

```
@Query("WITH dayscte AS (SELECT '+'|| :days ||' days')" +
    "SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE startDate >= :startDate AND startDate < date(:startDate,(SELECT * FROM ctedays)) AND jobId = :jobId")
```

or perhaps preferably :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE startDate >= :startDate AND startDate < date(:startDate,(SELECT '+'|| :days ||' days')) AND jobId = :jobId")
```

Using a variation of the above (simplified for convenience) i.e.

```
@Query("WITH dayscte AS (SELECT '+'||:days ||' days')" + " SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE startDate >= :startDate AND startDate < date(:startDate,(SELECT * FROM dayscte)) AND jobId = :jobId")
Shifts getShiftsTest(String days, String startDate, int jobId);
```

using :-

```
    long jobId = dictionaryDao.insertShifts(new Shifts("2019-01-01"));
    Shifts s = dictionaryDao.getShiftsTest("0","2019-01-01",1);
```

Returns the expected s as null (i.e. no rows extracted but the query was successfully run).

To test returning an actual value by adding a shortened version with a subquery rather than a CTE as per :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE startDate <= date(:startDate,(SELECT '+'||:days||' days')) AND jobId = :jobId")
Shifts getShiftsTest3(String days, String startDate, int jobId);
```

and :-

```
    long jobId = dictionaryDao.insertShifts(new Shifts("2019-01-01"));
    Shifts s1 = dictionaryDao.getShiftsTest("0","2019-01-01",1);
    Shifts s2 = dictionaryDao.getShiftsTest3("0","2019-01-01",1);
```

Results in (with a breakpoint added after ) produces (as expected) :-

[image]

Comment: the problem is Room doesn't  recognize `Date` without a set up

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher Room doesn't have to it is SQLite's date function used within a query. Just successfully run a variation of the above as a test with the expected result.

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher I have the converters, but that isn't the issue.  The problem is that room isn't recognizing `:date` inside the sqlite's `date()` function as a variable - because of the quotes I'm assuming.